# Blend For Visual Studio 11 get an error

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, blend, visual-studio-2012

- Installed Windows 8 Consumer Preview
- Installed Visual Studio 2010 Premium
- Installed Visual Studio 11 Ultimate

Everything installed without any errors.

I created a new Windows 8 Metro app using Visual Studio 11 and have no issues viewing xaml in VS 11 designer.  If I view it in Blend For Visual Studio 11 a propup with error:

*The project 'TestApp.csproj' could not be opened.  The imported project 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WindowsXaml\v11\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.CSharp.Targets' was not found.  Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.  c:\Users\testuser\Documents\Visual Studio 11\Projects\TestApp\testApp.csproj*

Also if I create a Windows Metro style project(any of the templates) in Blend For Visual Studio 11 it shows an empty solution after it's done.  When I look at the directory of where it suppose to create it I only see the project files but no solution.

Has anyone else had these issues?

Now the only question is how

**--Comment 1--**

No, path C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WindowsXaml**v11**\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.CSharp.Targets doesn't exist.  The path on the file system is C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WindowsXaml**v11.0**\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.CSharp.Targets

When I look at the project file this is what I see:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(VisualStudioVersion)' == '' ">
    <VisualStudioVersion>11.0</VisualStudioVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\WindowsXaml\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.CSharp.targets" />
```

The project file seems to be telling it the correct location so I'm not sure why it's trying to look in the wrong path?

**--End Of Comment 1--**

Comment: Is that the exact error?  The name of the targets file includes "CShar", which should presumably be "CSharp".  If you look in that folder, do the targets files exist there?

Comment: So no one else is having this issue?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this workaround from the known issues list:

> 1.3.3.35 Blend cannot create projects for Metro style apps built using HTML when Visual Studio 2010 is installed after Visual Studio 11 Beta 
>   When Visual Studio 2010 is installed after Visual Studio 11 Beta, the
>   installation **changes an environment variable to a variable that is
>   incompatible with Blend**.

(emphasis added)

To resolve this issue:

To work around this issue, do the following:

1. Right-click Computer, and then click Properties.
2. Click Advanced Properties.
3. In the System Properties dialog box, on the Advanced tab, click Environment Variables.
   [image: Environmental Variables]
4. Under System Variables, click New.
5. Under Variable name, type: VisualStudioVersion.
6. Under Value, type: 11.0.
   [image: Settings]
7. Click OK.

For Windows 8, to get to the environmental variables:

1. Do a search for *Advanced System Settings*
2. Make sure you have *Settings* selected on the right hand side
3. Select the *View advanced system settings* option

[image: Windows 8]

Comment: Thanks, helping bring this up in the search results